# Preserving cell properties between cells while using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

My application is a feed based application (think Instagram). Actually, it is very similar to Instagram - the difference is that instead of a picture, there is a swipeable, paginated view with different objects (link to demo):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYTjA3Bcv_A&feature=youtu.be

The swipeable functionality originates from this class: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView 
In my `UITableViewController` class I am trying to remain efficient with my memory by implementing `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. The problem this creates is that as you scroll and cells are being dequeued, the reusable nature of the cells carries over old data. 
My problem is that I want to preserve which object in the SwipeView a user had swiped to while still implementing `tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. 
 The property of the `SwipeView` that deals with this is `currentItemIndex`. This manages which item is currently centered in the SwipeView. Naturally, each `SwipeView` in the feed should remember its own `currentItemIndex`, however dequeueing cells carries over the old `currentItemIndex` from the cell that is being reused. This can be reset: `cell.swipeView.currentItemIndex = 0` while setting up the new (reused) cell, however then the old cell loses its `currentItemIndex` when it gets reused. 
Video of original problem: http://youtu.be/CXTHyvF3adI (see how the old `currentItemIndex` is transferred between `SwipeView` cells) 
 Video of problem when `currentItemIndex` is reset when a cell is reused: http://youtu.be/VBw8Rm-s5Qk (see how the `SwipeView` cells don't remember which item they were swiped to) 
 Does anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish this? 
Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: You need to store state somewhere other than the cell - in an array or NsIndexSer for example

Answer (score 0):

That is what PrepareForReuse method is for